# Why is putExtra is not passing the correct values from a service to an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has a service that tracks the user's location and compares it to a list of places, then when it finds a latitude/longitude match, it displays a custom notification. Tapping the notification then starts an activity, using a full screen intent, and passes a place name (string) from the service to the activity using putExtra/getExtras. This can happen multiple times as new places are found.

When I first install the app, this works perfectly. If the first place found is, say, London, the name London is passed to the activity correctly. However, if the next place is Bristol, the service has the correct name Bristol at the point where the notification is created (log.v below, labelled "show input"), but the activity still shows the name London (log.v below, labelled "show output") - the new name string is not getting passed across.

However many new places are found, the activity still shows the original name (London in this example) as the place. Also, if I stop and re-start the app, the activity still always shows the place as London, even if the first place found is somewhere else. The only way to get a new place name string passed across correctly is to uninstall and re-install the app.

The relevant code from the service is:

```
String placeName;

void createPopUpNotification(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.v("sTag","Create notification:  placeNumber = "+ placeNumber+"  placeName = "+placeName);//show input
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "notifychannel";
        Intent goShow = new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class);
        goShow.putExtra("plname",placeName);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, goShow, 0);
        RemoteViews expandedView=new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),R.layout.expandednotify);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.placename,placeName);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE ) ;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.amjnotify);
        builder.setCustomContentView(expandedView);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true);
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "mychannel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        builder.setChannelId( NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID ) ;
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationManager.notify(123, builder.build());
    }
}
```

and the code from the activity DisplayActivity is:

```
    int placeNumber;
    String placeName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    Intent goShow = getIntent();
    Bundle params = goShow.getExtras();
    placeName=params.getString("plname");
    Log.v("sTag","getParams:  placeNumber = "+placeNumber+"  placeName="+placeName);//show output
    goShow.removeExtra("plnumber");
    goShow.removeExtra("plname");
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand what is going on, and how to pass data (string in this case) correctly from the service to the activity?

Comment: Have you tried : `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` - `PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, goShow, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`.  Also make sure the `launchMode` of your `DisplayActivity` is standard in your manifest and not `singleInstance` or `singleTask` - if it is you will have to handle `onNewIntent` in your `DisplayActivity` by setting the intent and moving your current code into `onResume`

Answer (score 0):

copy this code and check

```
placeName=getIntent().getStringExtra("plname"));
Log.v("sTag","getParams:  placeNumber = "+placeNumber+"  
placeName="+placeName);//show output
goShow.removeExtra("plnumber");
goShow.removeExtra("plname");
```

Comment: you have put directly on string not a bundle set string time so you need to also get time directly string not a bundle

Comment: Thanks guys! These two suggestions together cured the problem.